# How to create users in MySQL4

Tags: mysql

I tried using the "create user" command in a MySQL4 database (something similar to what is available in the MySQL5 docs), but it failed. Can someone provide me the right syntax?

Comment: Have you looked at the old documentation? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/user-account-management.html

Comment: For what reason you are using Mysql4 and not Mysql5?

Comment: @Harry - Customer is still using 4 :(

Comment: What is the full `create user` command that you have tried so far?

Comment: @Tom - It didn't work with a create user, but worked with the grant statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users are created the first time you `GRANT` them a privilege.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/grant.html :

> > > The GRANT statement creates MySQL user accounts and grants rights to accounts.

So, let's say you have a database "mydb", with a table "mytable". If you want to create a user "jason", with the password "pwd123!" who has SELECT privileges on this table, you can do this:

```
grant select on mydb.mytable to 'jason'@'hostname' identified by 'pwd123!';
```

The usual caveats about hostname apply.

If you want to give jason full permissions on mydb:

```
grant all on mydb.* to 'jason'@'hostname' identified by 'pwd123!';
```

Important note: every time you use `identified by`, you're changing the password for that user/hostname, so you you will typically only use this syntax when creating a user!